# Qt: Using QTcpSocket -> I can write on socket, but I can't read...

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

I am using Qt 4.8 GCC 32bit on xUbuntu 14.04.
I have the following piece of code, a TCP server that I use in order to get some remote commands and send back some answers - via TCP socket:

```
struct _MyRequest
{
    unsigned long   Request;
    unsigned long   Data;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct _MyAnswer
{
    unsigned long   Error;
    unsigned long   Filler;
} __attribute__((packed));

_MyRequest request;
_MyAnswer  answer;

RemoteCmdServer::RemoteCmdServer(QObject * parent)
    : QTcpServer(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "Server started";

    listen(QHostAddress("172.31.250.110"), 5004);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(processPendingRequest()));
}

void RemoteCmdServer::processPendingRequest()
{
    qDebug() << "Process request";

    QTcpSocket * clientConnection = nextPendingConnection();
    connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()), clientConnection, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    // get the request
    int ret = clientConnection->read((char*)&request, sizeof(request));
    qDebug() << "READ: " << ret;
    if(ret == sizeof(request))
    {
        // send answer
        clientConnection->write((char*)&answer, sizeof(answer));
    }

    qDebug() << "Disconnecting...";
    clientConnection->disconnectFromHost();
}
```

I am able to write correctly if I comment the `if(ret == sizeof(request))` line.
Yet, I can't read from the socket (I always get 0 bytes).
I am 100% sure that the TCP-tool I use to send packets to my app works ok.
Here is the debug output from my app:

```
Server started     
Process request    
READ: 0     
Disconnecting...
```

What am I doing wrong? Please advise!

Comment: You must first wait for the data to become available before you try to read it. See [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html).

Comment: I tried, for 1000 msec... It doesn't seem to work... :(

Comment: Can you edit your question and show how you tried that? Are you sure data was sent during this 1 second period?

Comment: There are only few bytes, not a huge data size... I even tried to wait for 3 seconds and nothing... :(

Comment: Well keep waiting until you get the amount of bytes you expect to get.

Comment: I even tried to wait for 30 seconds(!) and still nothing. There are only few bytes to be received... 8 bytes in fact. So, I do have the feeling that I am missing something here or maybe I am on the wrong path...

Comment: Your `_MyRequest` struct looks like it should be 8 bytes. So why are you expecting more data?

Comment: Only 8 bytes, like in `clientConnection->read((char*)&request, sizeof(request));` where sizeof(request) I am 99% sure it is = 8. So, why do you say I am expecting more data?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for the data either in a non-blocking or blocking way. You can use [waitForReadyRead](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#waitForReadyRead) to do it in a blocking way.

```
void RemoteCmdServer::processPendingRequest()
{
    qDebug() << "Process request";

    QTcpSocket * clientConnection = nextPendingConnection();
    connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()), clientConnection, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    if (clientConnection->waitForReadyRead())
    {
        // get the request
        QByteArray message = clientConnection->readAll(); // Read message
        qDebug() << "Message:" << QString(message);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug().nospace() << "ERROR: could not receive message (" << qPrintable(clientConnection->errorString()) << ")";
    }

    qDebug() << "Disconnecting...";
    clientConnection->disconnectFromHost();
}
```

Comment: I tried using `clientConnection->waitForReadyRead(3000);` and it doesn't work at all. -> READ: 0

Comment: I updated my example code. Try to read the client message with readAll().

Comment: It says: "Network operation timed out", after calling `socket->waitForReadyRead(1000);`

Comment: You could try with the default value 30000 as well to see if 1 sec is too soon

Comment: I already tried that 3sec, 30secs etc and it doesn't work either. It seems the problem is somewhere else, I don't know for the moment. I hope someone smarter than me will come up with some other idea(s). Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I changed the machine and the cables and now it works. I guess it was something related to the wiring or firewall or god knows what else... Thanks for your time and patience! Regards, SG. Thumb up :)

Comment: Good that it works now. Anyway, there was a clear bug spotted in your code because you didn't wait for the data but assumed it was there immediately

Comment: Indeed, you're absolutely right! :) I guess 500 msec will be more than enough on a LAN / local network ?...

Comment: If blocking for some time is an issue then better implement non-blocking solution by connecting to readyRead signal. Otherwise, I don't think it harms if you use bigger value just to be sure not to timeout too easily...

Comment: 500 msec is more than enough to send 500 bytes via RS-232 serial cable @9600bps. So, I guess it would be lightning faster on LAN (with all TCP overhead), and finally I only need 20-30 bytes to receive, hehe :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read data from the new connection without returning to the Qt event loop -- I don't think that's going to work.

After you've accepted the connect with...

```
QTcpSocket * clientConnection = nextPendingConnection();
```

You need to connect to its `readyRead` signal with something like...

```
connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(my_read_slot()));
```

Where `my_read_slot` is the member function that will actually perform the read operation.